# Webscraping from embedded Microsoft Power BI table and graph

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, powerbi

**1. Summary of Problem**
I want to track and visualize COVID19 trends and time-series because I have to send my children to school in a state that forbids mask mandates and county without the courage to implement them anyway. Last week, I build a scraping routine for their website using `Python`, `Selenium`, and `Beautiful Soup`. It is not pretty, but it worked to grab the data and I built a Jupyter notebook to analyze the data. Here is the repository:

https://github.com/Rosenheim-Lab/PCS_COVID.git

As I worked on analysis and generated the first few figures, the county changed the format of their website for reporting the data. Now it is a website that seems to be driven by Microsoft Power BI and there is no link by which one can access the tabular data. There is still a visualization, and I wanted to know if there is anyway to scrape from this type of carpentry. Their COVID19 dashboard is here: https://www.pcsb.org/COVID19Cases .

**2. What I've Tried**
In the repo you can see that I have a Jupyter notebook-based scraping page employing a Python module as well as a Jupyter notebook for data analysis and visualization. I am new to web-scraping and had quite a bit of help from some friends. This is not the cleanest, leanest, meanest code, but it worked. Now it doesn't work because I am having trouble interacting with this new format through the Power BI UI.

**Code?**
I have not yet tried to code this out. The only way I did it before was with Selenium and a webdriver. I am having trouble finding where the tabulated data are in this new set up. I have done simple analysis like this:[image] and I wanted to keep that up. It would be great to get the data in the same format, however they are not presented in that format. Ultimately, I wanted to map the schools and compare the percentage infected to political maps of the county.